# Getting syntax error in Python in very basic program for no discernible reason

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm very new to Python as a language, and was just trying out some basic programs. For some reason, the code given below returns a syntax error, and does not give the location of the error.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
quest = raw_input("What is your quest? ")
color = raw_input("What is your favorite color? ")

print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
"and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color)
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Confirm this is working ok in Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 1):

When you print something in python, you need to put your whole message between parentheses. You can separate your values from text with comas.

**Try for exemple :**

```
print("Ah, so your name is,",name,"your quest is",quest,"and your favorite color is",color)
```

This is assuming you're working in python 3.